# Typescript error :: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got a problems about

> 'Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.'
>   'Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.'
>   'Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.'
>   'Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.'

on each `id`, `col`, `color`, `height`. for 4 times which are located in `ColsContextProvider`.

And I think it might be problem of `Colstate[]` but I cannot find the way to solve it.

```js
import React, { createContext, Dispatch, useReducer, useContext } from "react";

export const ADD_SQUARE = "ADD_SQUARE" as const;
export const CHANGE_SQUARE = "CHANGE_SQUARE" as const;
export const DELETE_SQUARE = "DELETE_SQUARE" as const;

export type Square = {
  id: number;
  col: number;
  color: string;
  height: number;
};

type ColState = Square[];

const ColsStateContext = createContext<ColState[] | void>(undefined);

type Action =
  | {
      type: "ADD_SQUARE";
      id: number;
      col: number;
      color: string;
      height: number;
    }
  | { type: "CHANGE_SQUARE"; id: number; col: number; color: string }
  | { type: "DELETE_SQUARE"; id: number; col: number };
type ColsDispatch = Dispatch<Action>;
const ColsDispatchContext = createContext<ColsDispatch | undefined>(undefined);

function colsReducer(state: ColState[], action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_SQUARE:
      return console.log("DELETE_SQUARE");
    case CHANGE_SQUARE:
      return console.log("CHANGE_SQUARE");
    case DELETE_SQUARE:
      return console.log("DELETE_SQUARE");
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function ColsContextProvider({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [cols, dispatch] = useReducer(colsReducer, [
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        col: 1,
        color: "#111",
        height: 80
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        col: 1,
        color: "#aca",
        height: 110
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        col: 2,
        color: "#cbb",
        height: 35
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        col: 3,
        color: "#aac",
        height: 20
      }
    ]
  ]);

  return (
    <ColsDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <ColsStateContext.Provider value={cols}>
        {children}
      </ColsStateContext.Provider>
    </ColsDispatchContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useColsState() {
  const state = useContext(ColsStateContext);
  if (!state) throw new Error("Cols provider problem");
  return state;
}
export function useColsDispatch() {
  const dispatch = useContext(ColsDispatchContext);
  if (!dispatch) throw new Error("Cols provider problem");
  return dispatch;
}
```

Comment: Given your example is not easy to reproduce elsewhere you could at least help by pointing the very line that triggers that error.

Comment: can you share stacktrace, it's impossible to determine issue without proper logs

Comment: type ColState = [] as Square[] might solve your problem.

Comment: Did u try `type ColState: Square[] = []` ?

Comment: @Kenny ''Square' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.' is occurred. and it says ''=' is expected'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a proper state in `colsReducer`.

You're returning `console.log()` in `colsReducer` function. That makes the return type of  `colsReducer` `void | Square[][]`, which is unable to infer, so the type of second parameter in `useReducer` becomes `never`.

Edit code like below, and see what you have to do.

```ts
function colsReducer(state: ColState[], action: Action) {
  // ...
}
```

change to:

```ts
function colsReducer(state: ColState[], action: Action): ColState[] {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my coding life.
And I perfectly understand it :)